Smallest rational affine space
Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. An rational affine space in $V$ means an affine space spanned by a collection of rational vectors (i.e., vectors $v=(v_1,...,v_n)\in V$ s.t. $v_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $i$).
Now, let $v=(v_1,...,v_n)\in V$ be a (not necessarily rational) vector. What is the smallest rational affine space containing $v$? And what are the form of the elements in this space?

I'm not sure there is a smallest one. There surely are minimal ones (and ones of minimal dimension, which in principle may not include all the minimal ones).
